# Вывод по одному элементу из каждого раздела

Tags: битрикс, фильтр, компоненты

Интересует построение фильтра для компонента news.list чтобы выбирал по одному элементу из каждого раздела инфоблока.

Например, есть инфоблок "Акции". В нём есть разделы "Продукты", "Бытовая химия" и прочие с соответствующими элементами. Необходимо выводить по 1 элементу из "Продуктов", "Бытовой химии" и прочих разделов.

```
$GLOBALS['myFilter'] = array(
    "IBLOCK_ID" => 11,
    "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
    ...
);
```

Comment: условия отбора? а вообще в настройках компонента есть опция сколько элементов показывать. и прочитайте обязательно [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Условия? Например, один самый "свежий" по дате элемент из каждого раздела. В настройках я выставляю общее количество элементов для вывода.

Comment: Тогда формируйте свой фильтр и передавайте его в компонент вместо стандартного. В документации есть описание как это сделать. CIBlockElement::GetList() Вам в помощь.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос в том и состоял: сформировать фильтр. Думал, у кого-то есть готовое решение вместо Getlist с вложенным циклом.

Comment: Зачем цикл? Цикла никакого не будет. Вы просто указываете гетлисту какие записи выбирать и он будет формировать вам список записей. Готового решения не будет так как фильтр каждому свой нужен серебряной пули тут нет.